getting information about shareable folders in telegram
I need to get information about channels that are contained in a shared folder, such as their id or username. But there are difficulties with writing, telegram declares that the folder is empty, although this is not the case. I will be glad to look at your ways to get this data. Thank you.
Link Type: https://t.me/addlist /...
Link to the documentation about common links: https://core.telegram.org/api/folders#shared-folders
from pyrogram import Client, errors
from pyrogram.raw.functions import chatlists
import pyrogram.raw.types as types
import asyncio

api_id = ""
api_hash = ""
session_name = "lalala" 

# Создаем клиент Pyrogram
client = Client(session_name, api_id, api_hash)

async def subscribe_to_folder(client, folder_link, session_name):
    try:
        await client.start()
        slug = folder_link.split("/")[-1]

        check_chatlist_invite = await client.invoke(chatlists.CheckChatlistInvite(slug=slug))
        peers = check_chatlist_invite.peers

        if not peers:
            raise ValueError("Folder is empty")

        updates = await client.invoke(chatlists.JoinChatlistInvite(slug=slug, peers=peers))

        print(f"[{session_name}] Success: {folder_link}")

    except errors.UserAlreadyParticipant:
        print(f"[{session_name}] User already participant: {folder_link}")

    finally:
        await client.stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    link = "https://t.me/addlist/yourlink"
    asyncio.run(subscribe_to_folder(client, link, session_name))

